# One-one relationship with different table namesin Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following tables.

**nyct2010**
[image]

and

**trips**

[image]

The models I have defined are below.

```
type Nyct2010 struct {
    Id      int `gorm:"column:gid"`
    Borocode int
}

type Trip struct {
    Id               int
    PickupLongitude  float64   `gorm:"column:pickup_longitude"`
    PickupLatitude   float64   `gorm:"column:pickup_latitude"`
    DropoffLongitude float64   `gorm:"column:dropoff_longitude"`
    DropoffLatitude  float64   `gorm:"column:dropoff_latitude"`
    PickupTime       time.Time `gorm:"column:pickup_datetime"`
    DropoffTime      time.Time `gorm:"column:dropoff_datetime"`
    Fare             float64   `gorm:"column:fare_amount"`
    Tip              float64   `gorm:"column:tip_amount"`
    Total            float64   `gorm:"column:total_amount"`
    PaymentType      string    `gorm:"column:payment_type"`
    Tax              float64   `gorm:"column:mta_tax"`

    Nyct2010   Nyct2010
    Nyct2010Id int `gorm:"column:pickup_nyct2010_gid"`
}
```

I am trying to get the related entry from `nyct2010`.  It is related to `pickup_nyc2010_gid`.

```
var trip Trip
db.First(&trip, 2112111736)

db.Model(trip).Related(&trip.Nyct2010)
```

The above code produces the following debug messages.

```
[2016-01-15 12:34:04]  [160.31ms]  SELECT  * FROM "trips"  WHERE ("id" = '2112111736') ORDER BY "trips"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

[2016-01-15 12:34:04]  pq: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" 

[2016-01-15 12:34:04]  [77.29ms]  SELECT  * FROM "nyct2010"  WHERE ("" = '1475')

[2016-01-15 12:34:04]  pq: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
```

For some reason gorm is ignoring the field that I am mapping `Nyct2010.Id` to, I am trying to map it to `Nyct2010.gid`.

Am I going about this wrong or is this an error with Gorm?

Comment: side comment: Id should be ID. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
type Nyct2010 struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primary_key column:gid"`
    Borocode  int
}

var trip Trip
var nyct2010 Nyct2010

db.First(&trip, 2112111736)
db.Model(&trip).Related(&nyct2010,"pickup_nyct2010_gid")
```

Comment: That did not work, I got the following...

```[2016-01-16 10:04:11]  invalid association [column:pickup_nyct2010_gid] 
```

Comment: Sorry. See updated answer. I will try to reproduce your error meanwhile. Can you post a sql with a table creation script?

Comment: I now get the following.  It seems gorm is ignoring the correct field and wants to use `id` instead.

`[2016-01-17 18:36:39]  [124.81ms]  SELECT  * FROM "trips"  WHERE ("id" = '2112111736') ORDER BY "trips"."id" ASC LIMIT 1`
 
`[2016-01-17 18:36:39]  pq: column "id" does not exist `

`[2016-01-17 18:36:39]  [57.39ms]  SELECT  * FROM "nyct2010"  WHERE ("id" = '1475')
[2016-01-17 18:36:39]  pq: column "id" does not exist`